# Simple rvm gui manager application

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rvm

I'm trying to write a simple gui application to manage ruby version manager.

I started with some stuff like testing how ruby's `%x[ ]` works..

I made this function

```
def do ( command )
  %x[#{command}]
end
```

but if I try to use this function with one of the rvm commands like `rvm list` or `rvm -v i` get

> a command not found: error.

The same function used with another command like `"ls -l"` or `rm -rf /*` XD  works correctly

Can someone explain to me why I get this error?

Comment: what is your progress on this? I hate RVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rvm` you run in your terminal is a shell function and not a command. The real `rvm` command is in `~/.rvm/bin/rvm`, and is most likely not in the path when you run `%x[…]`.

Comment: That's strange - I can do `system("rvm specific-ruby ruby bin/script.rb")` just fine.